# nginx ssl config, server certificate does not match the url

Tags: ssl, nginx

I create a ssl certificate but I the browser tells me that "the site is untrusted". Furthermore, the `https://` is crossed out and when the cursor hover over it, it says:

```
service certificate does not match the url.
```

I'm not sure how to configure the certificate to make it match. What I tried to do is to set the `Common Name` field in the certificate to match the name of my site: `example.com` but it didnt work.

Here is my certificate definition:

```
Issued To   

Common Name (CN)    example.com
Organization (O)    xxxx xxxx
Organizational Unit (OU)    xxxx xxxx
Serial Number   xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx

Issued By

Common Name (CN)    example.com
Organization (O)    xxxx xxxx
Organizational Unit (OU)    xxxx xxxx
```

Here is the corresponding nginx.conf:

```
server {

   server_name example.com;
   listen 443;
   ssi on;        

   ssl on;
   ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;

   client_max_body_size 4G;

   location =  / {
       ...
   }

   location ~ /.+ {
       ...
   }
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to proceed?

In the tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-nginx-for-ubuntu-12-04, right before "Step Six", it says

```
Additionally, make sure that both of these lines 
are commented out in the line toward the beginning of the file that says:

# Make site accessible from http://localhost/
# server_name localhost;
```

I dont have that. Is that the reason for the fault above? And if I need to do that, what does that mean for me?

Where will the following lines go, in the "server_name example.com" or "server_name localhost"?

```
location =  / {
    ...
}

location ~ /.+ {
    ...
}
```

And what does that mean? Why do I need this second server?

So again, how do I get rid of the error: `Identity of this website has not been verified. Server's certificate is not trusted.`?

Thanks in advance for your kind concern and time.

Comment: What is the URL to the server? If its really `mysite.com`, then you don't have a server listening: `openssl s_client -connect mysite.com:443` returns `connect: Connection refused`.

Comment: `Common Name (CN) mysite.com` - This is deprecated by both the IETF and CA/Browser forums. You should put a friendly name in the `CN`. Put your DNS names in the Subject Alternate Names or `SAN`. There can be multiple names, like `example.com`, `www.example.com`, `localhost`, `localhost.localdomain` and `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: jww@, no my friend, its not mysite.com. I just made that up ;) nice try. sorry ;) 
When I was going through the tutorial and using the openssl program, it didnt ask me for SAN. Can you tell me how to specify SAN to openssl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm not sure how to configure the certificate to make it match... Can you tell me how to specify SAN to openssl?

You need to use a configuration file. That's the only way to pass DNS names for the SAN to OpenSSL's `req` (request) utility (there's one other way, but its broken).

Below is a configuration file you can use as a template. Change the values to suit your taste.

***If*** you want to create a self signed certificate, then execute the following command. The inclusion of the `-x509` option creates the self signed certificate.

```
openssl req -config example-com.conf -new -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 \
    -nodes -keyout example-com.key.pem -days 365 -out example-com.cert.pem
```

***If*** you want to create a signing request, then execute the following command. The lack of the `-x509` option creates the request. It also lacks the `authorityKeyIdentifier` of a certificate.

```
openssl req -config example-com.conf -new -newkey rsa:2048 \
    -nodes -keyout example-com.key.pem -days 365 -out example-com.req.pem
```

You can inspect your handy work with:

```
openssl x509 -in example-com.cert.pem -text -noout
```

And:

```
openssl req -in example-com.req.pem -text -noout
```

---

> I create a ssl certificate but I the browser tells me that "the site is untrusted"

You're still going to need to import the self-signed so its trusted by your browser. But the problems with the names will go away. See for example:

- Firefox Support: [How do I trust a self-signed issuer certificate?](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/995117)
- TechNet IE Blog: [How to trust the IIS Express Self-Signed Certificate](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robert_mcmurray/archive/2013/11/15/how-to-trust-the-iis-express-self-signed-certificate.aspx)
- Google Chrome Product Forums: [Installing web certificates](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/bds-Ao9LigA)
- etc...

Each browser is different.

---

> And if I need to do that [nginx configuration], what does that mean for me?

I don't know about web server configurations. You might be able to get help at [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Web Apps Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/).

---

```
[ req ]
default_bits        = 2048
default_keyfile     = server-key.pem
distinguished_name  = subject
req_extensions      = req_extensions
x509_extensions     = cert_extensions
string_mask         = utf8only

[ subject ]
countryName         = Country Name (2 letter code)
countryName_default     = US

stateOrProvinceName     = State or Province Name (full name)
stateOrProvinceName_default = NY

localityName            = Locality Name (eg, city)
localityName_default        = New York

organizationName         = Organization Name (eg, company)
organizationName_default    = Example, LLC

# Use a friendly name here. Its presented to the user.
#   The server's DNS name show up in Subject Alternate Names. Plus, 
#   DNS names here is deprecated by both IETF and CA/Browser Forums.
commonName          = Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name)
commonName_default      = Example Company

emailAddress            = Email Address
emailAddress_default        = test@example.com

[ cert_extensions ]

subjectKeyIdentifier        = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier  = keyid,issuer

basicConstraints        = CA:FALSE
keyUsage            = digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
# extendedKeyUsage  = serverAuth
subjectAltName          = @alternate_names
nsComment           = "OpenSSL Generated Certificate"

[ req_extensions ]

subjectKeyIdentifier        = hash

basicConstraints        = CA:FALSE
keyUsage            = digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
# extendedKeyUsage  = serverAuth
subjectAltName          = @alternate_names
nsComment           = "OpenSSL Generated Certificate"

[ alternate_names ]

DNS.1       = example.com
DNS.2       = www.example.com
DNS.3       = mail.example.com
DNS.4       = ftp.example.com

# Add these if you need them. But usually you don't want them or
#   need them in production. You may need them for development.
# DNS.5       = localhost
# DNS.6       = localhost.localdomain
# DNS.7       = 127.0.0.1
```